# Google cloud cm intences not sending mail to users

Tags: email, server, centos, cpanel, whm

Hello hope you guys doing well,
For the last 3 days, I am trying to fix the issue with my VPS server it did not send any emails from the server to the user mail address.
I am new to server management.
hope you guys help me with something.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your problem is that Google Cloud blocks email sending by default on port 25. You need a smart host to fix this. Read the articles below for further information:

https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360041074753-Why-is-port-25-blocked-
https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360053203653